# Strange python settings + python import error

Tags: python, python-2.7, anaconda

Ubuntu 14.10. Just installed Anaconda (py 2.7).

when I type:

```
python
```

I get:

```
Python 2.7.9 |Anaconda 2.2.0 (64-bit)| (default, Mar  9 2015, 16:20:48) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux2
```

Why is this? And also my second problem (probably related) is I get ImportError when I try to import any module:

```
>>> import numpy
```

I get:

```
ImportError: /home/tomasz/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy
/core/multiarray.so: undefined symbol: PyUnicodeUCS2_FromUnicode
```

In addition: 
Anaconda (py 3.4) installs properly, however it is py 2.7 that I want.

Comment: Anything else wrong?

Comment: The first one, doesn't it give you a python shell ? numpy should be installed it's not part of python package.

Comment: Why is NumPy installed locally?

Comment: @alfasin, pretty sure it is installed with anaconda

Comment: @jakekimds I haven't noticed anything else

Comment: @tomtom try conda remove numpy and then reinstalling either with pip or conda

Comment: indeed looks like a wrong version of numpy is installed

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Every import module yields the same error.

Comment: So I think that Anaconda 2.7 compiles on my machine with wrong compiler (Red Hat - GCC 4.4.7) but have no idea why.

Answer (score 0):

Remove your `.local/lib/python2.7` directory. Things that are installed there will get picked up by any Python instead of its own site-packages, whereas you will want the Anaconda Python to be picking up its own numpy.